# Prove that f is differentiable at $0$

Tags: calculus

Here I got a question,

if f satisfies $|f(x)| \le |x|^9$ for all $x$, prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Can anyone give me some hints, now I have no clue to do this one.

Comment: You need to remember that $\displaystyle f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ or (equivalently) $\displaystyle f'(a) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$.  And you should also remember the idea of "squeezing".

Answer (score 9):

$f(0) = 0$, so consider
$$
\left | \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}\right | = \left | \frac{f(x)}{x}\right | \leq |x|^8
$$
Now let $x\to 0$

Comment: How do we know that f(0) = 0?

Comment: Since $|f(0)| \leq |0|^9 = 0$ :)

Comment: Oh right, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of differentiability: the limit $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0 + h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}$ should exist.